# Inputting Multiple XY Data from a .csv file in ArcMap to Create Flow Lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, flow-map

I am doing a project where I need to create a flow map in ArcMap 10.4.1.

I have imported the data from an Excel spreadsheet that I put together. The problem I am having is that when I Create A Feature Class from XY data, it only allows me to input one set of XY data. I have two sets of XY data in the spreadsheet (SiteUTMs and SourceUTMs), and need both in order to create the flow map. I cannot figure out how to get Arc to recognize the other set of XY data as coordinates to be an option in the dropdown menu in the XY to a Line tool. I tried reordering the columns in the spreadsheet to have the second set of XY data to be first in the spreadsheet, but Arc still only recognized the first set of XY data (the SiteUTMs), not the ones that I needed to add (the SourceUTMs.

I do have two other layers (one point and one polygon) that contain the information of the other XY data I need (the SouceUTMs), but there are two issues I am having with that. First, I cannot get Arc to join the layers and attribute tables with a join or relate. Secondly, in the XY to a Line tool, it only lets you input one layer source, so I cannot input both layers into the tool to have both sets of XY data that the flow lines need.

Here is a screenshot of the excel spreadsheet: 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What are the names of your Excel columns, and which ones are coming through into ArcMap?  Please [edit] your question to include as much detail as possible including any screenshots that may help.

Comment: The reason you can't see your second column is because of the `N/A`.  This is text in a number column, which means ArcGIS sees it as a text column (and therefore can't load values from it).  Remove these and replace with `0` or remove the records altogether

Comment: Further to Midavalo's comment, you need to 'Format Cells' for the second XY columns to a number.  Then they will show up in Arc.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information about your data it's only guesswork why the process isn't working for you. A way around this could be to use the [Points to line function](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/points-to-line.htm) instead.

In this case you only have one column with all of your points, end points and start points, together. The key here is to connect them with a new field, where the two points that should be combined have a common value. Example:

[image]

The points with a common LineID will be combined to a line (this is not limited to two points).